# How to display percentage of each row in Crystal Report Cross-tab?

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

I have resultset as below:

```
Year    Region    PeopleCount
2005    A         2
2006    A         15
2005    B         3
2006    B         35
```

I want to create the following report using CrystalReport cross-tab as below:

```
                    2005    2006
A    PeopleCount    2      15
     Percentage     40     30
B    PeopleCount    3      35
     Percentage     60     70
Total PeoleCount    5      50
      Percentage    100    100
```

Please give me some advise for create this kind of report.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Enter the Cross-Tab Expert by selecting Insert > Cross-Tab... from the menu.
- In the Cross-Tab tab of the Cross-Tab Expert

  - by highlighting each of the relevant fields and pressing on the `>` buttons next to the appropriate Cross-Tab section:

    - add Year to the Columns;
    - add Region to the Rows;
    - add PeopleCount to the Summarized Fields **twice**.
- In the Cross-Tab tab of the Cross-Tab Expert, click on the second `Sum of PeopleCount` summarized field and click the Change Summary... button. In the Edit Summary dialog, check the Show as a percentage of  Total:Sum of PeopleCount option and click OK to return to the Cross-Tab Expert.
- In the Customize Style tab of the Cross-Tab Expert, check the Suppress Row Grand Totals tickbox.
- Click OK at the bottom of the Cross-Tab Expert and add the Cross-Tab to the report footer. Click preview to check the results.

Comment: Could we have a line between PeopleCount and Percentage?

Comment: Yes - set the bottom border of the Sum of PeopleCount to be solid. To do this, right-click on the summary field in the Cross-Tab, select Format Field... from the menu, and in the Border tab of the Format Editor dialog select Single from the drop down menu for Bottom.

Comment: Could you solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780719/how-to-create-cross-tab-report-as-the-following-report