# How to create cross-tab report as the following report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

Is it possible to use Crystal Report cross-tab to create the following report?

Here is the report:

[image: Sample Report]

```
Growth Rate= (Last Year - First Year)/Total each Area
```

Here is my result set:

```
Year    Area    PeopleCount
2005    A       3
2005    B       2
....    ....    ....
```

If possible, please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your example data and pulled into a csv: http://speedy.sh/cY9d2/test.txt

Then built a report showing what you want: http://speedy.sh/XC4VJ/test.rpt

[image]

I'm sure there's an easier way but CrossTabs do introduce some difficulties. Here's the formula i've used in conjunction with a calculated member:

```
(
 (
  GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, GetNumColumns - 3, 0) 
  -
  GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, 0, 0) 
 )
 / GetTotalValueFor ("test_txt.Year")
)
* 100
```

Simply the `GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, GetNumColumns - 3, 0)` line takes the last value, the `GridValueAt (CurrentRowIndex, 0, 0)` line takes the first value and `/ GetTotalValueFor ("test_txt.Year")` line the total.

Let us know how you get on and if needed we can come up with some alternative solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But your report doesn't have growth rate.

Comment: I've added a screenshot... It's definitely there?

Comment: When I view your report, I don't see column growth rate, how to add it?